# Map `php` at the command line to point to `/usr/bin/php`?

Tags: php, linux, macos, unix, command-line

For some reason using `php` at the command line references `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of `/usr/bin/php`.  How can I make `$ php script.php` the equivalent of running `$ /usr/bin/php script.php`?

Current setup:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

Desired setup:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: create a Symbolic link `ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

Comment: There already is another version of php at `/usr/bin/php`, so I'd rather not overwrite that with a symbolic link.

Comment: ok, well its just one of many options :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change `$PATH` to contain `/usr/bin` first, or use your shell's alias capability to point `php` to `/usr/bin/php`.

```
alias php=/usr/bin/php
```